# How to vertically stretch a color input?

Tags: css, flexbox

Why does a color input not behave like all other input types when it comes to stretching height in a flexbox container?

In the code example shown below I tried to demonstrate the issue. As you can see all `input` elements except the one of type `color` are stretch to an equal height of the `strong` element.

What is going on and how do I still achieve a "stretched" color input height without using any static height styling values?

```css
.flexRow {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}
input {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
strong {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexRow">
  <input type="color" />
  <strong>Very high element</strong>
</div>
<div class="flexRow">
  <input type="submit" />
  <strong>Very high element</strong>
</div>
<div class="flexRow">
  <input type="text" />
  <strong>Very high element</strong>
</div>
```

This issue occurred to me on Firefox 63 and Chromium 70 on Ubuntu 18.04, please let me know if you **don't** have this issue with your setup.

Comment: Use `height` css attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well when you inspect the input type=color (with F12), you see the following:

```
input[type="color" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: square-button;
    width: 44px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color: buttonface;
    cursor: default;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
    border-image: initial;
    padding: 1px 2px;
}
```

The height is set to 23px and the other input elements don't have a fixed height, so they will resize with your `<strong>` tag.

if you set the style of the color input to height: auto; it will resize:

```
input[type="color"] {
    height: auto;
}
```